# get html source code from google search

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to extract data from this google search

https://www.google.com.ph/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=JQ7bVZjRDOSL8QeqibewAwgws_rd=ssl#q=scarlett+johansson+age

I want to get the age of an artist by getting this specific div tag

```
<div class="_eF">30 years (November 22, 1984)</div>
```

this is my code so far

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com.ph/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=eKfaVbWXBomM8QexmIOACw&gws_rd=ssl#q=scarlett+johansson+age").get();
Elements age = doc.getElementsByClass("#_eF");
String urlSource = age.html();
```

but all i get is the javascript code and not the actual html source

Comment: Why do you have `#_eF` when the class is clearly `_eF`?

Comment: either way it doesn't work,cause the value that is returned is javascript which does not contain any of the two.(#_eF and _eF)

Comment: Show us what it gives you.

Comment: it gives the actual page source `_.Ib=!_.L||9<=_.Hb;_.Jb=!_.sb&&!_.L||_.L&&9<=_.Hb||_.sb&&_.N("1.9.1");_.Kb=_.L&&!_.N("9");_.Lb=_.L||_.qb||_.M;
}catch(e){_._DumpException(e)}
try{
_.x("gbar.elr",function(){return{es:{f:152,h:60,m:30},mo:"md",vh:window.innerHeight||0,vw:window.innerWidth||0}});
}catch(e){_._DumpException(e)}
})(this.gbar_);
// Google Inc.`

Comment: Try what Deximus just posted as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong. By doing `doc.getElementsByClass`, you get multiple results (or however Jsoup handles those).

What you want to be doing is:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com.ph/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=eKfaVbWXBomM8QexmIOACw&gws_rd=ssl#q=scarlett+johansson+age").get();
Elements age = doc.select("div._eF");
String urlSource = age.html();
```

Comment: it doesn't work, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078926/how-does-google-hide-html-source-of-search-results i red this post, google build page's dom by javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);\
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://link.com/");
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3000);
DomElement el = page.getElementById("_eF");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may switch technologies. Instead of Jsoup you could use [Selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), which will basically remote control a webbrowser. This should be perfectly capable of rendering the HTML from the AJAX call.

Alternatively you could find out what google actually returns and which API URL is called. You could then parse the response directly. Likely they use JSON, which is easy to parse. there are quite a few libraries out there for handling this. ([JSON-Simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/), [GSon](https://github.com/google/gson), [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to name a few)