# How can I retrieve the "inspected source code" (Google chrome) in Java?

Tags: java, web-scraping

Okay so I am learning **Web Scraping** and best way to learn something is by actually doing it. I am comfortable with Java hence I choose [Jsoup](http://www.jsoup.org), which is a web scraping library. I planned on Scraping Google although I know the outcome of it [source](http://google-scraper.squabbel.com). Scrapping Google result seems to be easy but what I found difficult id scraping all the displayed content, which is not possible as most of it is dynamic [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078926/how-does-google-hide-html-source-of-search-results),Google does that by generating the page using a pile of client side JavaScript .I scraped the search result using the following code here

```
 package JsoupPrac; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import org.jsoup.Jsoup; 
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document; 
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element; 
import org.jsoup.select.Elements; 

public class GoogleScraper { 

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{ 
Document doc; 
try{ 
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.co.in/search?as_q=&as_oq=query&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=lang_en&cr=countryCA&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=&gws_rd=cr&ei=4Id1Vs7pC8rQjwOEkbP4CA#lr=lang_en&cr=countryCA&as_qdr=all&tbs=lr:lang_1en%2Cctr:countryCA&q=query")
.userAgent("Mozilla").ignoreHttpErrors(true).timeout(0).get();

 Elements links = doc.select("ol[class=g]"); 
for (Element link : links) { 
Elements titles = link.select("h3[class=r]"); 
String title = titles.text(); 
Elements bodies = link.select("span[class=st]"); 
String body = bodies.text(); 
System.out.println("Title: "+title); 
System.out.println("Body: "+body+"\n");
 } 
} catch (IOException e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
 }
 }
```

So with the above code and iterating it a bit with

```
a[href]
```

and looking for

```
abs:href
```

I can get the list of all urls as well.

Now what I found difficult is to get all the content available on the search result page, which is not available in the source but can be found with the inspect element. So **my question is, is there a way (maybe 3rd party) to collect all the source code that we get when we inspect any web page n Google Chrome using Java**.

Comment: Are you sure that `"all the source code"` isn't already being returned from scraping?  I can't imagine why JSoup would be filtering anything from the HTML result out.

Comment: Well all codes are not available  because of it's being java scripted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way (maybe 3rd party) to collect all the source code that we get when we inspect any web page in Google Chrome using Java.

Yes, we can do exactly that - automate a real browser via [`selenium`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html?overview-summary.html).

Initialize a driver object, navigate to a URL and get the [`driver.getPageSource()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource%28%29):

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(url);

// sometimes here we might also need to wait for the page to load

System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

You can feed the page source returned by selenium to `Jsoup`, but note that `selenium` itself is *quite powerful in locating elements* - you may not even need a separate HTML parser.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, the page source that we will retrieve it will wont the be codes that we get when we inspect a page in google chrome, is it?

Comment: @silverFoxA in this case the same source code as you inspect manually.

Comment: Thank you it does work as intended, there's one query I have is how the same can be implemented in a smartphone without the browser being loaded?

Comment: @silverFoxA good! You can actually automate mobile browsers via selenium and appium.